# riak - query all buckets by meta field

Tags: riak

I have a use case for an aggregate query across the entire db and all buckets, I'm wondering the best query method to use, leaning towards multiple secondary index calls. This won't be a frequently used feature, possibly invoked once a week or so via scheduled job or something.

Some records have a value in their meta attribute that I'd like to match/target for the selection.

From what I've read, secondary index looks great but it is limited to a single bucket?  I also saw "list buckets", which has warnings about production use, though not sure if that's applicable to such infrequently used functionality.  Thought maybe i could list buckets then perform the secondary index query on each.

Is there a better way?  MapReduce seems heavy, having to load every KV of the file system. Search seem possible too but index setup/maintenance seems overkill if there's an easier way.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you happen to already have a query working but are wondering if it's the best way to accomplish your goal?  If so, can you provide that here so that we can give you a better answer?

Comment: thanks! No nothing written yet, still figuring out the approach. Looking at the Search option, possibly using a field with a good analyzer for a strict/absolute match.